# Does the Meier-G function have a lower and an upper bound?

Tags: functions, special-functions, upper-lower-bounds

The [Meijer G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function) is given by

[image]

It serves as a solution to certain differential equations, and has been shown to generalize a variety of elementary and transcendental functions.

Is there a lower and upper bound on this function?